# How to add aggregates and group tuples in TFDMemTable?

Tags: delphi, firedac, fdmemtable

I have 2 `TFDQuery` objects connected to 2 different databases from which I'm fetching tuples and merging them into a single `TFDMemTable`. This works fine, but now I need to group those merged tuples and create certain aggregate fields.

For example, `FDQuery1` and `FDQuery2` having tuples of the following structure:

```
Country | UserName | BillCount | BillAmount | BillDiscount
```

I need to group them having aggregate fields like this:

```
Country | UserName | sum(BillCount) | sum(BillAmount) | sum(BillDiscount)
```

How to do this with FireDAC?

Comment: You can add [Aggregates](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.Aggregates), to them then set grouping index.

Comment: Thank you victoria for the response. I am extremely new to FD, it would be really helpful if you could show that with the above example. I went through the web but i am not able to understand the usage.